# Where is the IPython output image?

Tags: python, ipython, visualization, plot

I tried to follow the examples at [`Quantum Circuit Plotting with SymPy`](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/rpmuller/5843312) but I could not find the output picture.

My OS is Ubuntu and I typed all the commands in the terminal of IPython, as you can see here:

[image]

The output is similar to the one in that website,

```
<sympy.physics.quantum.circuitplot.CircuitPlot object at 0x7fa125ee5c10>
```

So, where is the output figure? In some folder?

PS: I run again and get another similar but different output

```
<sympy.physics.quantum.circuitplot.CircuitPlot at 0x7f6ff0903690>
```

Comment: What command/tool have you used and how did you get that result? What is it supposed to do and what is not doing?

Comment: I never used this software but as I understand this you should not get the pictures that you see on the website on your terminal. That is even impossible to print using chars. It should be data on a variable that should be used with another tool that actual display that data as a graphic. Why do you think you should see the output on the terminal?

Comment: He isn't asking why he can't see it in the terminal, he's asking how he gets those images, the plots - what is the author using to create those plots from the outputted data

Comment: Isn't the output a QASM file?  Then there is a package, qasm2circ, to turn a QASM file to a figure, as explained in the very first link on your linked webpage... btw, this is not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Thanks! The output is not a QASM file. The author want to use python to do what the latex package qasm2circ can do.

Comment: You have all the necessary dependencies like matplotlib?  In any case, you'd be better off asking in a SymPy forum, not an Ubuntu one.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Thanks! matplotlib is OK. I will ask in a SymPy forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install ipython python-sympy python-matplotlib # for Python 2.x in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier
```

or

```
sudo apt install ipython3 python3-sympy python3-matplotlib # for Python 3.x
```

Start the IPython interpreter with the `--pylab` option like this: `ipython --pylab` to enable showing the output plot as shown in the below screenshot. The Python code in the screenshot is identical to the code in the question.

[image]
<sup>**X gate test**</sup>

Comment: It works! Why we must need ipython notebook? Why would not other editors work? For example, IPython QT console.

Comment: bounty worthy.. definitely

Comment: @karel Thanks! I typed an example in the QT console but there is no figure output.

Comment: @karel Thanks! Then the key point is that `--pylab` is necessary and will not auto-start?

Comment: If you try running `CircuitPlot(CNOT(1,0),2)` without the `--pylab` flag, you get only the text output that says something like: `<sympy.physics.quantum.circuitplot.CircuitPlot at 0x103844f90>`. At this website: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/python-matplotlib/filelist you can see that the pylab.py file comes from the python-matplotlib package.

Comment: IPython Notebook is not necessary. The `--pylab` option of `ipython` also works in the terminal.